# Declare *and* initialize a table variable in a single statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I can declare and initialize simple variables in the same statement:

```
Declare @DO_BIG_UPDATE Int = 0;
```

How do I do that with table variables??

```
Declare @USERS table (Id Int identity primary key, Status Int Not Null, LoginId VarChar(64) Not Null) = (
    1,1,'asdf',
    2,2,'asdf'
);
```

This is SQL Server Management Studio 18.8

Comment: As SSMS is purely a client UI the version is rarely relevant. What is relevant is the version of your SQL Server i.e. `select @@version;`

Comment: Quick check of the docs would have told you it's impossible https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: A table variable? No. A #temp or ##temp table? Yes, via `select into`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, but no you cannot do that. It is not valid syntax for declaring table variables (as of SQL Server 2022).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-local-variable-transact-sql

So you will need two statements:

```
declare @USERS table (
    Id int identity primary key, 
    [Status] int not null, 
    LoginId varchar(64) not null);

insert into @USERS values
    (1, 1, 'asdf'),
    (2, 2, 'asdf');
```